# Link a SO en español en SO en ingles?

Tags: característica-nueva

Yo no me había dado cuenta que ya estaba funcionando SO en español hasta el dia de hoy que se me ocurrió buscarlo en Google.

Sospecho que puede haber otros en mi situación, o inclusive el visitante casual de SO en ingles no sabe de SO en esp.

No soy un programador WEB experto, pero creo se puede detectar el idioma o pais del usuario, siendo asi, **se puede agregar un link en el SO en ingles que apunte a SO en español que solo aparezca a los usuarios de habla hispana?**

Algo asi como [Stack Overflow en español ahora disponible!](https://es.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: Es una buena sugerencia, aunque quizás esto debería sugerirse en el meta de StackOverflow en inglés en lugar de en éste.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro No, la sugerencia esta en el lugar perfecto aquí.

Comment: @JuanM Comprendo que son sitios relacionados y dentro de la "misma familia", pero se está sugeriendo en el sitio Y añadir un cambio para el sitio Z. En mi opinión, lo lógico sería hacer esa sugerencia directamente en el sitio Z.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Tu razonamiento es bueno.  Pero, siendo que el cambio afectaría a nuestro sitio, lo mejor es proponerlo aquí y permitir que el gerente de comunidades (yo mismo) pueda presentar el argumento a la empresa.  Este tipo de preguntas se debe hacer aquí aunque afecten a otro sitio en la red.

Comment: Entendido. La verdad es que estaría bien que se implementase.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se ha hecho algo similar con el sitio japonés.  Permíteme investigar más información sobre esto.  Me parece una idea muy buena.

---

Pedi que se formularan unas imágenes para nuestro sitio que también liguen a los usuarios cuyo navegador esta en español para invitarlos a nuestro sitio.  En cuanto estén activos, les aviso aquí.

Comment: En japonés no lo sé, pero lo han hecho en portugués y los anúncios aún si quedan por allá. Mira esta [imagen que acabé de sacar](http://i.stack.imgur.com/1CSDg.png).

Comment: esto esta en proceso - gracias @Math :)

Comment: Excelente saber eso!!! :)

Comment: Los anuncios se están creando ahora.  Falto poco tiempo para que estén en vivo en el sitio de inglés.

Comment: Alguna noticia?

Comment: Lamentablemente, no. He seguido pidiendo que se haga una realidad y por lo que llevo entendido, están ya creadas las imágenes. En cuanto tenga noticia, lo anuncio aquí.

Comment: @JuanM Quizás es buen momento para reactivar este tema. Con la última campaña que lanzaron **[tuvimos un buen envión](https://www.quantcast.com/es.stackoverflow.com?country=GLOBAL#trafficCard)** y creo la comunidad respondió bien (los índices de respuestas/por preguntas/aceptadas/etc. siguen similares). Creo que sería genial aprovecharlo ahora sumando una campaña en SO.

Comment: @Mariano Hace ya varios meses pusimos unos anuncios en SO invitando a la gente que tiene su browser en español a este sitio. Los resultados no han sido estelares y estamos pensando en otras iniciativas para aumentar nuestro alcanze. Si tienes alguna sugerencia ¡por favor compártela!

Comment: @JuanM Disculpame. No sabía y pensé que era una buena idea. Nunca había visto al anuncio, pero quizás me filtró por ser usuario de SOes. Desde luego, cada vez que puedo intento dar sugerencias tratando de sumar.

Comment: @Mariano Se aprecia el apoyo y el cariño que demuestras al sitio.  Necesitamos a cien más como tu.